# Eas Build (Expo) task app:CreateReleaseExpoConfig is missing module jsonfile/utils. How would I resolve it?

Tags: react-native, expo, gradlew, eas

I'm trying to migrate to using eas-build from expo build. I created a simple eas.json and I'm stuck on fixing this (hopefully) last error.

I didn't have a .env file before moving to eas-build so I'm quite sure that's not the issue.

package.json snippet:

```
"expo": "^41.0.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
```

And my eas.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.1.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting in the "run gradlew" step on Expo:

```
> Task :app:createReleaseExpoConfig FAILED
[stderr] node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
[stderr]   throw err;
[stderr]   ^
[stderr] Error: Cannot find module 'jsonfile/utils'
[stderr] Require stack:
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/index.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/build/ios/index.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/build/index.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/android/SplashScreen.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/android/index.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/index.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config/build/plugins/withConfigPlugins.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config/build/Config.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config/build/index.js
[stderr] - /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/scripts/getAppConfig.js
[stderr]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
[stderr]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
[stderr]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
[stderr]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
[stderr]     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json.js:3:23)
[stderr]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
[stderr]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
[stderr]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
[stderr]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
[stderr]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
[stderr]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[stderr]   requireStack: [
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/output-json.js',
[stderr] '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/index.js',
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js',
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/build/ios/index.js',
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/build/index.js',
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/android/SplashScreen.js',
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/android/index.js',
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/index.js',
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config/build/plugins/withConfigPlugins.js',
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config/build/Config.js',
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config/build/index.js',
[stderr]     '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-constants/scripts/getAppConfig.js'
[stderr]   ]
[stderr] }
> Task :unimodules-permissions-interface:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unimodules-image-loader-interface:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unimodules-react-native-adapter:packageReleaseResources
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:createReleaseExpoConfig'.
[stderr] > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 2m 16s
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `expo` SDK is deprecated (SDK 41), which can cause a lot of problems when building with `eas`.

A lot of times this issue is resolved by upgrading your SDK to a non-deprecated `expo` SDK version.

Follow the instructions on upgrading your SDK and run `eas build -p android --profile development` or `eas build -p android --profile preview`

[Upgrading Expo SDK](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/)